# Motive of CM elliptic curve and modular forms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, modular-forms, complex-multiplication

I am trying to get some insight into the Deligne/Scholl construction of the motive of a modular form. First of all I would like to understand the case of weight two, especially when there is complex multiplication. Unfortunately in his paper "[Motives for modular forms](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01231194)" Scholl says

"We do not treat here the case $k = 0$, which corresponds to cusp forms of weight 2; the associated motives are then given by the Jacobians of modular curves, and are well understood."

**Question 0**: Could anyone explain this or give a readable reference?

More precisely, I am interested in the following question. If $E$ is an elliptic curve over a number field $K$, one can look at the Chow motive with rational coefficients
$$
h^1(E)
$$ cut off from the total motive $(E, \nabla, 0)$ by $\nabla$ minus the two projectors associated to some rational point (over an extension of $K$ if necessary). In general, this motive is indecomposable.

However, when $E$ has complex multiplication by a quadratic imaginary field $F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$, one gets a decomposition of $h^1(E)_F$ into two rank 1 motives with coefficients in $F$.

On the other hand, one can look to the weight two modular form $f$ attached to $E$ (modularity in the CM case, which is much easier!). Thanks to the construction quoted by Scholl one gets a rank two motive with coefficients in the field generated by the Fourier coefficients of $f$.

**Question 1**: (General elliptic curve) What is the relation between these two motives? One would like to say there are the same, but the coefficient field are different,  aren't?

**Question 2** (CM case): Does the geometric construction using Jacobians of modular forms also give the decomposition into two pieces of rank one? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Since this question has come alive again, let me point out that the Hecke operators cannot give a splitting of $h^1(E)$ into two pieces over $F$, since the Hecke correspondences on a modular curve are always defined over $\mathbf{Q}$.

(If you allow some extra stuff like the Atkin--Lehner operator on $X_1(N)$, then you can get some slightly larger fields showing up, but they will still be totally real, and thus not capable of "seeing" the splitting of $h^1(E)$.) (EDIT: Actually I am not sure if this is true, sorry!)

If you take a higher-weight CM cuspform $f$ of weight $> 2$, associated to some Groessencharacter $\Psi$, then the situation is even worse: you can define a motive associated to $f$ using Kuga--Sato varieties, and a motive associated to $\Psi$ using the product of $k-1$ copies of an elliptic curve with CM by $K$. These motives really should be the same, because their $\ell$-adic Galois representations are the same for every $\ell$, but there is (as far as I know) no natural way of writing down a correspondence that gives an isomorphism between them in the category of Chow motives.

Comment: Allowing the more general Hecke correspondences attached to double cosets $KgK$ in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$, we get correspondences defined over the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_N)$ where $N$ is the level of $K$ (e.g. the building blocks of a modular abelian variety $A_f$ are not defined over $\mathbb{Q}$).

Comment: Maybe the reason is that the complex multiplication endomorphisms of $E$ are not defined over an abelian field in general.

Comment: No, this isn't the reason. If $E$ is a CM elliptic curve defined over $\mathbf{Q}$, coming from a CM-field $K$ with class number one, then the CM-endomorphisms are all defied over $K$, which is quadratic and thus certainly abelian over $\mathbf{Q}$. But I think the field of definition of the Hecke correspondences is the real subfield $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)^+$ of $\mathbf{Q}(\zeta_N)$.

Comment: I think it depends on the level $\Gamma \subset \mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbb{A}_f)$: some building blocks in $J_1(N)$ are defined over fields which are not totally real.

Comment: You are right, sorry, I slipped up calculating the field of definition of the components.

Answer (score 3):

The construction alluded to by Scholl is the Eichler–Shimura construction, and a readable account can be found e.g. in D. Rohrlich, [*Modular curves, Hecke correspondences, $L$-functions*](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4612-1974-3_3).

If $f$ is the newform of weight 2 associated to a CM elliptic curve $E/K$, then the abelian variety $A_f/\mathbf{Q}$ associated to $f$ by Eichler–Shimura is isogenous over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$ to a power of $E$. But some extra work is needed in order to get the minimal field of definition of this isogeny. I don't think it's always true that the isogeny is defined over $K$ — you could imagine replacing $E$ by an elliptic curve which is isomorphic over $\overline{\mathbf{Q}}$, which preserves the CM condition. **EDIT** : One should also be careful with what is meant by the modular form associated to $E$. It is rather a Grössencharakter over $K$ which is associated to $E/K$. In order to get a classical modular form, I think one should further assume that $K$ is (at most) quadratic.

That being said, if $K'$ is a field of definition of the isogeny $A_f \sim E^n$, then the motive of $A_f$, which is just the restriction of scalars of the motive of $f$, is isomorphic to $h^1(E)^n$ over $K'$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, François! Do you know something about the second question, that is, how to see the two submotives of rank one in $A_f$? 

Comment: This is a good question -- on the Galois side, the Galois representations associated to $f$ and $A_f$ decompose into two rank 1 pieces after restricting to the absolute Galois group of the imaginary quadratic field $F$ by which $E$ has CM. These pieces are cut out by the endomorphisms of $E$ which are not defined over $\mathbf{Q}$, and we may wonder whether these endomorphisms are modular i.e. are induced by some Hecke correspondences on modular curves above $f$. I think this should be true at least in some cases, but I'm not sure and I hope an expert of the CM case can show up.

Comment: I once saw a result stating that the Hecke correspondences generate the whole endomorphism algebra of the Jacobian of a modular curve, so the answer should be yes, but I don't recall the reference.

Comment: So where is this CM expert? :)

Answer (score 1):

**Question 1:** The field generated by the Fourier coefficients of an elliptic curve associated to a modular form is $\mathbb Q$. (For example, since the Fourier coefficients can be calculated by counting points on the elliptic curve, which gives integer values.)

**Question 2:** I think the answer is "no".